# Converting an obsolete 240V clothes dryer connection to useful supply for 2 radiant heat projects

Tags: dryer, radiant-heating

I have a 240V dryer connection no longer used on a dedicated circuit and a three-wire, plus ground wire going to it. Since it's no longer in use, I was thinking of using it to supply power to 2 radiant heat projects.  The first project is for an 80 square-foot bathroom using 120V, using one of the hot wires and the neutral, employing 12 gauge wire of course.  The second installation, would be using both hot wires for the 240V radiant heat for 140 square feet of basement space, again using 12 or 10 gauge.  Does anyone see any problems with this plan?  Thank you.

Comment: What are the rated sizes (Watts or VA or Amps) of the two heaters?

Comment: As per the manufacturer, it's 8 Amps for 80 square feet and I already have the mat.  The 240V mat I'm about to purchase.

Comment: A link to manufacturer's specs or brand/model #s would be *very* helpful.

Comment: Looks like a subpanel with one 1-pole 15 A breaker and one 2-pole 15 A breaker would allow 14 AWG conductors to the heating mats. If a 30 A breaker is in the main panel, could the two breakers have ratings totalling 30 A?

Comment: @JimStewart Yes, that would be fine. And could even be a bit more - e.g., if the 120V 15A breaker has a hardwired 8A load and no receptacles (it can't have receptacles, actually, due to the 50% rule) then it would account for 10A on one leg, so the 240V breaker could be 20A with a continuous load up to 16A. Though if it has a continuous load 12A or lower then it would only account for 15A x both legs, and then the subpanel could *also* have a 15A 120V general use receptacle circuit.

Comment: @JimStewart The big problem with the subpanel solution is the required 30" x36" open space - unlikely that an old dryer location would have that open space, but if it does then a subpanel would be ideal.

Comment: Thank you, Jim Stewart.  Excellent suggestion.